# Entity Framework OnModelCreating - check for missing DB-objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently setting up a system, where basic server side security for the SQL server to client connection is achieved by views for each user (Windows authentification). 
The main table `Entries` that's holding all the data got

```
DENY SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON [dbo].[Entries] FOR public
```

, so the only way to access the data for the users is to use their corresponding view `ENTRIES_USER`('User' is a placeholder), which explicitly gets a

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[Entries_USER] TO [DOMAIN\user]
```

. Also, default permissions for `public` are reduced, so nobody else can read from the view. Everything working so far, and now comes the cool stuff.

---

I'm connecting to this DB with Entity Framework and "CodeFirst" (it's on an existing DB, but mapping happens at runtime), like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>().ToTable("Entries_" + Environment.UserName.ToUpper());
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Projects");
}
```

The connection string enables Windows Authentification, the object mapping is realised with Annotations. 
What I don't know, is how to check before trying `Entity().ToTable(...)` if this table exists. If it doesn't, I want to make a call to a stored procedure, that creates a new view for the user.
I already tried to put the `ToTable`-Call inside a try-catch, but this doesn't cause an exception even if it can't connect properly.

Is there a way to check in advance, <s>without using hard coded SQL-queries</s>, if the table/view I want to map to already exists? And if not, can I somehow react when EF-mapping failed , do some action (the stored procedure call), and retry?

EDIT: I decided that manually checking with a query should be ok, if there isn't a "clean" solution. Is there a way to get the server connection in `OnModelCreating`, or do I have to create one on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, but only with an own connection. I can't use the existing one, because the DbContext prevents me from accessing it inside OnModelCreating.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    string viewname = "Entries_" + Environment.UserName.ToUpper();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    using (SqlCommand initCmd = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = @ViewName) exec dbo.spAddUser @User, @Domain", connection))
    {
        // the connection string is the same one I use to create the DbContext
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        initCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ViewName", viewname);
        initCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User", Environment.UserName);
        initCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Domain", GetDomain());            
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            initCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            // TODO
        }
    }
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>().ToTable(viewname);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Projects");
}
```